# Access violation writing location 0x0000000C error while calling c++ dll from c#

Tags: c#, c++, swig

**What I do**:

1. I called a C++ dll from C#. It works fine but when I exit the process, it shows the following error

   > exe stoped working
2. When I debug the code in Visual Studio it shows

   > Unhandled exception at 0x773C77A2 (ntdll.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000C.

**The code I have used in C#**:

```
using System;
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Utility test1 = new Utility();
            algobucket test2 = new algobucket();

            Console.WriteLine("Algobucket Algorithm\n ");
            int k = 1;
            byte[] imageData1 = new byte[5000000];
            byte[] imageData2 = new byte[5000000];
            int[] target1 = new int[1000];

            while (k == 1)
            {
                int m;
               
                test1.CameraRead(imageData1);
                int a = test2.iristracker(imageData1, 640, 480, imageData2, target1, 1000);
                m = test1.ImageShow(imageData2);

                if (m == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
                    break;                    
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Exited");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code the dll is called in the lines

```
                test1.CameraRead(imageData1);
                int a = test2.iristracker(imageData1, 640, 480, imageData2, target1, 1000);
                m = test1.ImageShow(imageData2);
```

The CameraRead() and ImageShow() are called from a dll and the iristracker() is called from another dll.

**Utility.h**

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_H

class Utility
{

public:
 int CameraRead(unsigned char* Output);
 int ImageShow(unsigned char* Input);
int DrawRectOnImage(unsigned char* image,int* rect,int n);
int DrawPointOnImage(unsigned char* image,int* rect,int n);
};

#endif  /* UTILITY_H */
```

**Iristracker.hpp**

```
#ifndef IRISTRACKER_HPP
#define IRISTRACKER_HPP
#include <iostream>
class algobucket 
{

public:


 int iristracker(unsigned char* input,int width,int height,unsigned char* Output,int* output,int n,std::string xml_path="");  

};

#endif  /* IRISTRACKER_HPP */
```

**Swig Interface Utility.i**

```
%module testing

%{
#include "Utility.h"
%}
%include "arrays_csharp.i"

  %apply unsigned char OUTPUT[] { unsigned char* Output}
   %apply unsigned char INPUT[] { unsigned char* Input}
   %apply unsigned char INPUT[] { unsigned char* image}
  %apply int INPUT[] { int* rect}
 %include "Utility.h"
```

**Swig Interface Iris.i**

```
%module algo

%{
#include "IrisTracker.hpp"
%}
%include "arrays_csharp.i"
%include "std_string.i"
  %apply unsigned char INPUT[] { unsigned char* input}
  %apply unsigned char OUTPUT[] { unsigned char* Output}
  %apply int OUTPUT[] { int* output}
 %include "IrisTracker.hpp"
```

Here missed any typemap for Memory handling for above swig interface file

What do I have to do to solve this issue?

Comment: The issue is likely in the code not presented here. How is the dll imported? What does the C++ code look like? Are you sure those array are sufficient? You will need to reduce this to a [mcve]. The error message is typical of a buffer overrun (possibly in some string).

Comment: [A marshalling problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454665/calling-unmanaged-c-library-dll-from-c-sharp-creates-an-access-violation-err?rq=1)?

Comment: Further, check the calling conventions on the imported functions. The C++ default `cdecl` vs. what .Net assumes as a default `stdcall`. Mismatches in the stack causes problems.

Comment: @Niall I imported the dll using the wrapper file generated using the swig.

Comment: @CibinWilliam You didn't mention which one of those line(s) calls the DLL.  Second, that is a bad design if the client has to guess how many bytes to allocate, and cross their fingers that it is enough.  The way it's usually done is that the DLL creates the memory, and returns the memory along with the size that was created.  Or if not that, the client provides the maximum size as a parameter.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 
 test1.CameraRead(imageData1);
 int a = test2.iristracker(imageData1, 640, 480, imageData2, target1, 1000);
  m = test1.ImageShow(imageData2);

These three methods are called from two different dll

Comment: @CibinWilliam You should post that information in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have updated the question,pls check

Comment: @CibinWilliam Why did you pick 500,000 bytes as the size?  I am somewhat familiar with image data (not knowing exactly what format the camera uses), and 500,000 bytes is not large, depending on image format.  The call to `CameraRead` is what I'm referring to.

Comment: From what I know of SWIG, there may be an error with your definitions etc. There may be further questions there you may want to pursue; but you will need to reduce the scope of the problem.

Comment: Looking at the `iristracker` definition -- Default parameters in C++ are a part of the C++ language.  What makes you believe that C# understands this?  Second, usage of `std::string` as a parameter to a DLL function is highly limiting for the same reason -- a `std::string` is only known by C++ -- C# has no idea what it is.  I know people use SWIG, but I contend that they need to understand what is being generated and whether it makes sense.

Comment: @PaulMCKenzie SWIG has automation features,that will make sense to namespace std to understand for the target language.
%include "std_string.i"

Comment: @CibinWilliam SWIG cannot circumvent the basics of interfacing a C++ DLL to C#.  What you should do is open your DLL in a tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and note the exact signature of the exported function.  If the `std::string` appears at the end of the signature, then there is no way that C# could make that call successfully, given that the DLL function requires that parameter to be sent (and your C# code does not).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Swig Automated .cs file
  public int iristracker(byte[] input, int width, int height, byte[] Output, int[] output, int n, string xml_path) {
    int ret = iristrackerPINVOKE.algobucket_iristracker__SWIG_0(swigCPtr, input, width, height, Output, output, n, xml_path);
    if (iristrackerPINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Pending) throw iristrackerPINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Retrieve();
    return ret;
  }

Comment: No, what I mean is to take the DLL, use Dependency Walker, and see what the exported function is and post it.  Once you do that, then you will get more help.  There are two issues, whether the C# declared properly, and whether you're providing buffers that are actually big enough to hold the data.  With the first issue, once the exported function is known, then we know exactly what should be declared, SWIG or no SWIG.